# How to get the height of an external/off-site image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to get the height of an external image using Javascript ?

Comment: without preloading it?

Comment: You have to *completely* load an image into the DOM before you can measure the dimensions of it.

Comment: `.naturalHeight`, it does not require jQuery. It being external makes no difference, you would need to preload a local image too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a preloading of the image and find it like

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.onload = function () {
    console.log(this.height, this.width)
}
img.src = '//placehold.it/64X45'
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vjJ9u/)

Comment: The Fiddle does not work, because jsfiddle handles `console.log` in some fancy way. Better use `alert` there.

Answer (score 3):

can't do this without loading image.
you can use javascript `Image` object to do this :

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function(e) {
    alert('Height : ' +e.currentTarget.naturalHeight + ' width:'+e.currentTarget.naturalWidth);
};
image.src = 'link goes here';
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WZhuJ/2/)

Answer (score 1):

No its not possible out the box. It would only give you the mime type and the content-length. 
You have to load the image to find out its pixel width and height.

Alternatively you could programmatically add the dimensions in the response header (if you have access), which you could then use the http "HEAD" command to just have the headers returned.

Comment: While what you say is true, you do not show how to do what you suggest. I wouldn't be surprised if this answer gets downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible to do it with **ImageInfo - Javascript Image Meta Data reader**:
http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/08/imageinfo-reading-image-metadata-with.html
*(header can be fetched, but depends on the file type tho as per the script description)*

**Demo here:**
http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/imageinfo/

I haven't tried it, but I remember looking at this and thinking a similar approach. It quotes that:

> Since the header information is usually only a very small portion of
>   the image file, there's an option to only request a number of bytes
>   from the beginning of the file. By setting `ImageInfo.useRanges = true`
>   and `ImageInfo.range = <n>`, only the first `<n>` bytes will be
>   downloaded. However, since the position of the header information in
>   JPEG files isn't fixed (neither is the size of any EXIF data), this
>   has been left as an option. If you're not using it with JPEG files or
>   if you know your JPEGs don't have embedded thumbnails, you should be
>   safe to set it to only get the first few KBs or so.